# PHP - multiple email addresses

Tags: php, email

Here is my php so far

```
$headers  = "From: webinquiries@someplace.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: sales@someplace.com\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: someone@someplace.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\n";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

how do i add three more email addresses to this list

Comment: What list? None of those is a list.

Comment: Here's a library, not hard to learn http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ you can do loops with it etc etc *see examples*

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a string with comma-separated e-mail addresses, or any other string that complies with RFC 2822.

Please read the [mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function documentation in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of email addresses, loop through each item in the array and call the `mail()` function. Or submit a comma separated list like so `User <user@example.com>, Another User <anotheruser@example.com>`.

If your emailing 'needs' require sending an extensive amount of emails, you might want to look into some third party libraries, as the `mail` function is very 'delicate'.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) - they eliminate the hard work in creating MIME-based emails, and allow any number of To/CC/BCC addresses in any combination.